# build geoserver with maven (monitor-hibernate)

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, build, geoserver

Can someone tell me how to build a java application (in this case the "monitor-hibernate" plugin for geoserver) with maven?

The fact that the plugin "monitor" was divided into two: monitor-core and monitor-hibernate. The monitor-hibernate plugin is installed in addition to monitor-core. The monitor-hibernate plugin allows you to save the log to a database (for example, postgresql).

The problem is that the monitor-hibernate project uses org.springframework.orm.hibernate3. And the POM does not specify a version:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Downloaded SpringFramework version 5.1.1 in which there is no org.springframework.orm.hibernate3. And the project is not going under Ubuntu 18.04.

Please tell me how to build this plugin for Geoserver 2.16.x not changing the version of SpringFramework under Ubuntu.

Build is performed correctly only in 2.14.x.
But in 2.16.x uses SpringFramework version 5.1.1.
At that time, monitor-hibernate was built on version 3.x.y...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the whole of the [GeoServer tree](https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver) - `${spring.version}` is defined in the top level [`pom.xml` file](https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/blob/master/src/pom.xml#L1968). So for 16.x it is:

```
<properties>
  <gs.version>2.16-SNAPSHOT</gs.version>
  <gt.version>22-SNAPSHOT</gt.version>
  <gwc.version>1.16-SNAPSHOT</gwc.version>
  <jts.version>1.16.1</jts.version>
  <spring.version>5.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
  <spring.security.version>5.1.5.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
```

However, looking the [Community Module build repository](https://build.geoserver.org/geoserver/2.16.x/community-latest/) it seems that monitor-hibernate is not present and a [check on github](https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/commit/0af20936ed46c8781088d398250818f7d25723d3) shows it was kicked out of the build in October 2018.

If this is an important module for you then [you can work on a fix](http://geoserver.org/devel/) and [submit a PR](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/developer/policies/pull_request.html) or sponsor a [commercial organisation](http://geoserver.org/support/) to make the fixes needed for you.